# How do I treat a rose tree that appears to be in shock but still has rose hips and has plenty of root suckers?

Tags: trees

I have two Sunny Knock-out rose trees that were transitioned from pots to sunny landscape areas in the front of my home. The trees appear to be in shock. If not for the Sucker roots extending above the ground I would have thought they were dead. Should I cut the sucker roots and the rose hips off or should I just leave the trees alone for now? The rose hips remain from last fall.

Answer (score 4):

Bit of clarification required here - are you saying that you had two (probably standards) rose trees, but there is nothing growing at the top, you just have a dead stick with no growth, but you have plenty of growth from below ground level, and that growth has hips from last year?

If what I've said is correct, then your roses are dead - what's still alive is the rootstock they were grafted to, and that probably isn't something you want to keep at all, so best dig it out before it gets much bigger and becomes a tangled mess of dogrose and thorns....